# Check presence of an application on Android device

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

Actually, I am putting a check on my application that whether one particular application is present or not in device if it is present than only my application will launch otherwise it will give a dialog to download that particular app to proceed.

As of now i am checking it using the application package name or application name but the problem in android is another app can also have the same name and package name. So if user will uninstall the original app and make an app with the same package name I am hacked.

So is there any  way to stop me hacked means can we check the application presence with some unique thing like keystore or something which can't be same even if user install the another app having the same package info.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider checking the verification signature? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938298/how-does-androids-app-signature-verification-work

Comment: Hope this link would help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922606/detect-an-application-is-installed-or-not